# How to get a Swift type name as a string with its namespace (or framework name)

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to get a Swift type name as a string with its namespace (or framework name)?

For example, if `Foo.framework` has a class named `Bar`, I would like to get a string something like `"Foo.Bar"`.

The followings just return the class name `"Bar"`.

```
let barName1 = String(Bar.self)       // returns "Bar"
let barName2 = "\(Bar.self)"          // returns "Bar"
let barName3 = "\(Bar().dynamicType)" // returns "Bar"
```

I would like to also get the framework name `"Foo"` as a namespace.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`String(reflecting:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1541282-init):

```
struct Bar { }

let barName = String(reflecting: Bar.self) 
print(barName) // <Module>.Bar
```

From the [Xcode 7 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html):

> Type names and enum cases now print and convert to String without
>   qualification by default. `debugPrint` or `String(reflecting:)` can still
>   be used to get fully qualified names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer with the reference to the release note too. I remembered the type name was printed with its module name before, but I was not sure my memory was correct. I appreciate that you told me the String initializer changed its default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`String(reflecting:)` works right now, but could change in the future. So if you only need the fully-qualified name temporarily, you should be fine. However, if the name is something you're going to rely on over a longer period of time (spanning multiple releases of Swift) you shouldn't use it.

The Swift community is trying to come to a consensus on a longer-term method for getting the information from a type.

From Joe Groff:

> In 4.2, String(reflecting:) still shows a fully qualified name for local types, but the local type context is anonymized and printed in a way that's intended to be clear is non-stable, since no matter what reflection support we add in the future, it'd be a bad idea to incidentally rely on the presence or identity of local types in dynamic code.

https://forums.swift.org/t/getting-the-more-fully-qualified-name-of-a-type/14375/9