# Self.Type cannot be directly converted to AnyClass in extension to objective-c class in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, type-inference, swift-extensions

I'm trying to create fabric method to create UIViewController with correct nib name (to fix iOS8 default initialiser issue). To do it I have added extension:

```
extension UIViewController {    
    class func create() -> Self {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            return self.init()
        } else {
            let clsName = NSStringFromClass(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
            return self.init(nibName: clsName, bundle: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

However compiler issues error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Self.Type' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')` in `NSStringFromClass(self)`.

To fix it another extension method can be added and code rewritten to:

```
extension UIViewController {
    private class var nibNameForInitializer:String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }
    class func create_() -> Self {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            return self.init()
        } else {
            return self.init(nibName: self.nibNameForInitializer, bundle: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

However I want to understand the problem with first variant.

As I understand, method returning `Self` is a kind of generic method. `Self` can be used in many contexts (e.g. class, struct, protocol, etc), however `Self.Type` matches `AnyClass` only for classes.

In my case, compiler should know that `Self` refers to `UIViewController` and all its subclasses (since it is inside `UIViewController` extension), so `Self.Type` must be convertible to `AnyClass`.

Do I miss anything, or it is correct behaviour, since compiler doesn't perform any additional type analysis for `Self`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a bug or an (unnecessary) restriction, so you might
consider to file a bug report at Apple. It happens only
for type methods with return type `Self`. As a workaround, you can write

```
let clsName = NSStringFromClass(self as! AnyClass).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
```

which compiles and seems to work as expected.

But there is a simpler way to get the same result:

```
// Swift 2:
let clsName = String(self)
// Swift 3:
let clsName = String(describing: self)
```

Comment: Wow, Kudos to you for getting the same answer as me in almost the same time haha

Comment: For Swift 3 the last line should probably be "let clsName = String(describing: self)".

Comment: Or even better, "String(reflecting: self)", except that it's apparently undocumented. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32087449/253938

Comment: @RenniePet: That would include the module name (e.g. "MyApp.MyViewController") which might not be wanted here (the class name is used as the nib file name). –It was documented at least in some release notes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33452915/1187415.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it is a bug, try forcing a downcast,  that is how I had to get this to work:

```
let clsName = NSStringFromClass(self as! AnyClass).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
```