# iOS: Passing Parameters to private Framework while Initializing a UIViewController

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, ios-frameworks

I am trying to create a custom framework that I can use across my apps. When I instantiate my first `ViewController` from my framework in the app, I would like to pass in two parameters.

```
import UIKit

public class NewVC: UIViewController {
    public var startColor: String?
    public var endColor: String?

    public required init(startColor: String, endColor: String) {
        self.startColor = startColor
        self.endColor = endColor
        super.init(nibName: "sb", bundle: nil)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to instantiate `NewVC` in my `AppDelegate`:

```
import NewVCFramework
//...
let vc = NewVC(startColor:"00ff33a", endColor:"ff0c756")
let s = UIStoryboard(name: "sb", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: vc))
//I get an error on the line above that points at vc
self.window?.rootViewController = s.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Below is the error that I get:

```
Error:  Cannot convert value of type 'NewVC' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnObject.Type')
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567189/self-type-cannot-be-directly-converted-to-anyclass-in-extension-to-objective-c-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `NewVC` instance to the `UIStoryboard` init method, that expect class. Use `NewVC.self` instead.

Also, if you use storyboard, `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will be called instead of your custom init. You can provide `startColor` and `endColor` values after view controller instance creation

Code below should fix your problem:

```
import NewVCFramework
//...
let s = UIStoryboard(name: "sb", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: NewVC.self))
let vc = s.instantiateInitialViewController() as !NewVC // Will call init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) for NewVC
vc.startColor = "00ff33a"
vc.endColor = "ff0c756"
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: Thanks.  I put print statements.  I got passed the error, however,  vc.startColor and endColor are showing up as nil.