# How to get swift mangled object name

Tags: swift

I've learned that swift actually creates a naming method called "mangling" used internally for all objects.

All threads talk about demangling, **but how to actually get the mangled name?**

i've tried
1- object_getClass(self)
2- NSStringFromClass(MyClass.self)
but they return the normal class name.

I've found this demangle project..
https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlDemangle/blob/master/CwlDemangle/CwlDemangle.swift
is there a mangling project maybe?

Note: Im using swift 3.0.1

Comment: What is the purpose you need mangled names for? Maybe it can be achieved in another way.

Comment: workaround for binding swift iOS framework to xamarin iOS, where the bridge between swift and C# requires the actual class name.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://owensd.io/2015/01/14/compiling-individual-files/) can help you.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452771/how-to-get-a-swift-type-name-as-a-string-with-its-namespace-or-framework-name) can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xcode ships with a command line tool to de-mangle names.

Type in:
`swift demangle`

Then find your mangled class name..
`__TMaC17find_the_treasure15YD_Secret_Class`

Then watch it spit out the name..
`find_the_treasure.YD_Secret_Class`

If you want to observe the mangled names, as you asked, you can put the produced Swift iOS or macOS binary into a dissassembler like `Hopper`, `iDAPro` or `radare2`.

The tools to automatically de-mangle names are already here (refer to `Hopper v4.0 Dissassembler`).