# Get full, namespaced, Swift type name

Tags: swift

I know that I can get a string representing a type like so:

```
String(describing: MyType.self)
```

However, I would like to get the type name including its scope, like this:

```
struct MyType {
    struct Nested {}
}
```

I would like to get "MyType.Nested" from `Nested` instead of just "Nested". Or at least something different than if I were to get the string for:

```
struct MyOtherType {
    struct Nested {}
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452771/how-to-get-a-swift-type-name-as-a-string-with-its-namespace-or-framework-name ?

Comment: @MartinR thanks, that does answer my question. Looks like there isn't a stable way to do it yet.